# how to do an ifelse inside a for

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to do a loop but I don't know what is wrong.
And another question: can the code be more "elegant/fast/clean"?

```
library(dplyr)

db <- tibble(
  year = seq(1870, 1990, by=1),
  mainsample = rbinom(length(year), size=1, p=0.9)
) 

for (i in seq(1870, 1920, by=5)) {
  db$sample = ifelse(db[,c("year")] == i  & db$mainsample == 1, 1, 0)
}

## A tibble: 6 x 3
#year mainsample sample
#<dbl>      <int>  <dbl>
#1  1870          1      0 ----> 1
#2  1871          1      0
#3  1872          1      0
#4  1873          1      0
#5  1874          1      0
#6  1875          1      0 ----> 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need either `$` or `[[` as `[`.  In addition, the `sample` column is getting updated in each iteration.  We need to store the output and `Reduce` it

```
v1 <- seq(1870, 1920, by = 5)
out <- vector("list", length(v1))

for(i in seq_along(v1)) 
   out[[i]] <- ifelse(db[["year"]] == v1[i]  & db$mainsample == 1, 1, 0)
db$sample <- +(Reduce(`|`, out))
```

---

Or this can be avoided by doing another condition

```
db$sample <- 0
for(i in seq(1870, 1920, by = 5) ){
   db$sample <- ifelse((db$year == i & db$mainsample)|db$sample == 1, 1, 0)
}
```

-output

```
> subset(db, year %in% seq(1870, 1920, by = 5))
# A tibble: 11 × 3
#year mainsample sample
#<dbl>      <int>  <dbl>
#1  1870          1      1
#2  1875          1      1
#3  1880          1      1
#4  1885          1      1
#5  1890          1      1
#6  1895          1      1
#7  1900          0      0
#8  1905          1      1
#9  1910          1      1
#10 1915         1      1
#11 1920         1      1
```

---

Or use `%in%` without a for loop

```
db$sample <- ifelse(db$year %in% seq(1870, 1920, by = 5)  &
        db$mainsample == 1, 1, 0)
```

The `ifelse` is not required as we could coerce the logical to binary (TRUE -> 1 and FALSE -> 0)

```
db$sample <- with(db, +(year %in% seq(1870, 1920, by = 5) & mainsample == 1))
```

Comment: Ty for your answer @akrun the `for` doesn't work for me, but the code (`%in%`) works. why?.

Comment: @cdcarrion sorry, earlier I overlooked your assignment.  the `sample` column got updated in each iteration, thus returning only the values from the last iteration.  ( i updated the code)

Comment: ty @akrun, in the first block it shows `Error in out[[i]] <- ifelse(db[["year"]] == v1[i] & db$mainsample == 1,  : more elements supplied than there are to replace`. The 2nd block it's strange for me [creating  `db$sample <- 0`] (is there any way to solve my code without doing another condition?).

Comment: @cdcarrion it is a copy/paste error.  I initially created as an integer, and then created the list.  sorry. updated

Comment: @cdcarrion For the second one.  We initialize the column as `df$sample <- 0` then loop over and replace the `sample` with the check that if there is a sample value of 1, it remains as 1.  otherwise, the df$sample is getting updated in each iteration and you will get only the sample values from the last iteration.  It is almost similar to your code.  I just wanted to use same code with minimall changes

Comment: now the error on the 1st block is `Error in df$sample <- +(Reduce(`|`, out)) : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. So, if I do a `for` like this (creating a variable with condition. Do I need  to create a variable at the beginning `db$sample <- 0` and then `ifelse(... condition ... | sample == 1)`?

Comment: @cdcarrion i can't reproduce that error.  I copy/pasted the same code including your original data

Comment: @cdcarrion for the first code block, you don't need `sample` column created initially

Comment: @cdcarrion thanks for correcting the typo. (df vs db)

Comment: the question `if I do a for like` was referred to for the second block.

Comment: @cdcarrion that requires `db$sample <- 0` initialization as we use  condition `|db$sample == 1`